# splitting a flatfile using timestamp as new line instead of \n

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a flatfile and am trying to create a dataframe using read_csv and I'd like to use a timestamp as the spot where a new row starts instead of a new line. I don't want to use \n because when there's an error in the flatfile, the errors take up multiple lines, but they still start with a single timestamp. I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.file',header=None,sep='\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
```

This does a couple of things I don't want it to do - first, it deletes the yyyy-mm-dd out entirely leaving just the time part (I need to keep it), and second it didn't seem to actually split only at the timestamp, it still is splitting it up where it finds \n

Example:
normal line:

```
2022-05-16 hh:mm:ss here's a normal line in the file \n
```

error line:

```
2022-05-16 hh:mm:ss here's an error \nhere's error details \nit's a new line even though it's the same error \nbut it just has one timestamp
```

normal line current output:

```
hh:mm:ss here's a normal line in the file
```

normal line desired output:

```
2022-05-16 hh:mm:ss here's a normal line in the file
```

error line current output:

```
hh:mm:ss here's an error
here's error details
it's a new line even though it's the same error
but it just has one timestamp
```

error line desired output:

```
2022-05-16 hh:mm:ss here's an error here's error details it's a new line even though it's the same error but it just has one timestamp
```

Comment: It would help if you could add some example data.

Comment: Plus,  your intended output.

Comment: added example, let me know if that needs clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to read in the file and then fix it.  This approach finds all the lines that start with timestamps, groups by them and then concatenates all the strings in that group.

The data:

```
str_io = io.StringIO(
'''2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in the file
2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error
 here's error details
 it's a new line even though it's the same error
 but it just has one timestamp
2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal line in the file
2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line in the file'''
)
```

(You'll have to mess with setting `sep=` for your use-case).  Can no longer do `sep='\n'` in `1.4.2`.  You can use a char that doesn't exist in the file - like back-tick - to read entire lines.

```
df = pd.read_csv(str_io, header=None)
df

0  2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...
1                2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error
2                               here's error details
3    it's a new line even though it's the same error
4                      but it just has one timestamp
5  2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...
6  2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...
```

Find the rows that start with a timestamp (you will think of something better for your use-case than "starts with a '2'":

```
ts_rows = df[0].str.startswith('2')
```

Then accumulate the error rows text and attach them to the previous timestamped line:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill().groupby('ts') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' ')).reset_index(drop=True)

0    2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...
1    2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  here's er...
2    2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...
3    2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...
```

This shows that the error lines were accumulated:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill().groupby('ts') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' '))[1]
    
"2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  here's error details  it's a new line even though it's the same error  but it just has one timestamp"
```

Then you can break up the lines into columns like `ts` and `message` or whatever you need for your specific application.

**How it works**

To start with, the timestamps are extracted from the rows that contain them.

```
df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)

0    2022-05-16 01:mm:ss
1    2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
5    2022-05-16 03:mm:ss
6    2022-05-16 04:mm:ss
```

The following assigns that to a new column named `ts`:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19))
```

It is equivalent to the following (but `assign` allows you to do that assignment on the fly).

```
df['ts'] = df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)
```

So the dataframe now looks like:

```
                                                   0                   ts
0  2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...  2022-05-16 01:mm:ss
1                2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
2                               here's error details                  NaN
3    it's a new line even though it's the same error                  NaN
4                      but it just has one timestamp                  NaN
5  2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...  2022-05-16 03:mm:ss
6  2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...  2022-05-16 04:mm:ss
```

The next step is forward fill the timestamps so that we can associate the error lines with a timestamp:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill()

                                                   0                   ts
0  2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...  2022-05-16 01:mm:ss
1                2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
2                               here's error details  2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
3    it's a new line even though it's the same error  2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
4                      but it just has one timestamp  2022-05-16 02:mm:ss
5  2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...  2022-05-16 03:mm:ss
6  2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...  2022-05-16 04:mm:ss
```

Now that the we know the timestamp for each error line we can group and concatenate the error string using `.str.cat()`.

But first, here is how `.str.cat()` works:

```
errs = pd.Series(['err1','err2','err3'])
errs

0    err1
1    err2
2    err3

errs.str.cat(sep=' ')

'err1 err2 err3'
```

So `.groupby('ts').apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' '))` does that for all lines within a timestamp:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill().groupby('ts') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' '))
    
ts
2022-05-16 01:mm:ss    2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...
2022-05-16 02:mm:ss    2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  here's er...
2022-05-16 03:mm:ss    2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...
2022-05-16 04:mm:ss    2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...
```

Which leaves the timestamp as the index which I didn't think you wanted so `.reset_index(drop=True)` gets rid of that:

```
df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill().groupby('ts') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' ')).reset_index(drop=True)
    
0    2022-05-16 01:mm:ss here's a normal line in th...
1    2022-05-16 02:mm:ss here's an error  here's er...
2    2022-05-16 03:mm:ss here's a another normal li...
3    2022-05-16 04:mm:ss here's a third normal line...
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain this portion a little more? I am unfamiliar with this. It worked, but I'd like to understand it: df.assign(ts=df[ts_rows][0].str.slice(0,19)).ffill().groupby('ts') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[0].str.cat(sep=' ')).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation.